# Can a nested SVG be used as input for feTile in an SVG?

Tags: xml, svg, svg-filters

I'm using `feTile` in combination with `feOffset` in an SVG file to create a shadow filled with a pattern. The pattern itself is an SVG file too. To keep the complete SVG self-contained, I would like to embed the pattern in it and not reference an external file.

The ugly workaround I found, is to base64-encode the pattern file. This code produces the expected result:

```xml
<svg>
    <defs>

        <!-- Base64-encoded below-->
        <!-- <svg id="pattern1" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'> -->
        <!--   <rect width='10' height='10' fill='#fff' /> -->
        <!--   <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="#000"/> -->
        <!-- </svg> -->

        <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">

            <!-- This does not work -->
            <!-- <feImage width="3" height="3" result="checkerboard-image" xlink:href="#pattern1" /> -->

            <feImage width="3" height="3" result="checkerboard-image"
            xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxMCcgaGVpZ2h0PScxMCc+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9JzEwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEwJyBmaWxsPScjZmZmJyAvPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEiIGN5PSIxIiByPSIxIiBmaWxsPSIjMDAwIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==" />

            <feTile in="checkerboard-image" result="texture" />
            <feOffset dx="30" dy="20" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/> <!-- this contains the offset blurred image -->
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> <!-- this contains the element that the filter is applied to -->
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <rect fill=white stroke=black x="10" y="10" width="200" height="100" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" />
</svg>
```

I tried nesting the pattern-SVG and referencing it with it's ID (see code comment in code), but that doesn't show anything.

Is it possible to do something like this to reference another SVG for the pattern?

```xml
<feImage width="3" height="3" result="checkerboard-image" xlink:href="#pattern1" />
```

EDIT: I found a way, but it only seems to work in chrome/chromium, firefox e.g. does not render it correctly. Also, adding more `rect`'s with the filter is still not working properly

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="svg24" width="100%" height="1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs id="defs15">
    <g transform="scale(0.25)" id="dotted-pattern">
        <rect style="fill-opacity:0" id="pattern-box" width="16" height="16" />
        <circle style="fill:#000" id="pattern-circle1" cx="10" cy="10" r="2" />
        <circle style="fill:#000" id="pattern-circle2" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" />
    </g>
    <filter
       id="dropshadow"
       height="1.154449"
       x="-0.0044999999"
       y="-0.0049999999"
       width="1.0582259">

      <feImage width="4" height="4" result="pattern-image" href="#dotted-pattern" />
      <feTile in="pattern-image" result="texture" id="feTile4" />

      <feOffset dx="11" dy="15" result="offsetblur" id="feOffset6" />
      <feMerge id="feMerge12">
          <feMergeNode id="feMergeNode8" /> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" id="feMergeNode10" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" x="10" y="10" width="200" height="100" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" id="node2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: SVG is xml format and binary data must be encoded.  Base64 string is one means of accomplishing results.  Usually in SVG which has mult-layers graphics the layers are a URL to a file.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455986

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, according to the SVG 1.1 specs, yes. Regarding feImage, https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feImageElement states

> This filter primitive can refer to an external image or can be a reference to another piece of SVG.

This statement is unchanged in the specs for SVG 2.

I tried your edited code with the g element converted to an svg element, and both rendered OK in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Two comments related to your shadowing in general:

1. Besides using a different pattern, the original version makes a shadow of dots on a white background while the edited version has a transparent background for the shadow, which may not be what you want.
2. Unless the intended shapes to be shadowed are all rectangular, you will also need to filter the shadow to the shape of the SourceGraphic since feTile tiles its entire primitive subregion. So even circles get rectangular shadows.